# uint8_t to uint16_t

Tags: c

How do you convert a uint8_t to a uint16_t?

currently im breaking down uint16_t to uint8_t like this:

```
    packetBuffer.header[0] = ((co2Val>>8) & 0xff);
    packetBuffer.header[1] = (co2Val & 0xff);
    packetBuffer.header[2] = ((humVal>>8)&0xff);
    packetBuffer.header[3] = (humVal & 0xff);
    packetBuffer.header[4] = ((tempVal>>8)&0xff);
    packetBuffer.header[5] = (tempVal & 0xff);
```

co2Val,humVal and tempVal are all uint16_t

however, i'll need to change them back to get the corresponding value. This is received at the other end as uint8_t buf[16].

this is how i did it:

```
    CO2Val = (buf[0]<<8)|buf[1];
    HumVal = (buf[2]<<8)|buf[3];
    HumVal = (HumVal & 0x0fff);
    TempVal = (buf[4]<<8)|buf[5];
    TempVal = (TempVal & 0x3fff);
```

The results are different. Anyone know why? thanks

Comment: Could you show some examples of the incorrect results you get? You should also choose to tag this question either C or C++ but not both, since the answers are likely different.

Comment: How do the results differ? Also, why do you mask out bits of `HumVal` and `TempVal`?

Comment: By the way, the `& 0xff` operations in your code are all redundant clutter. Any assignment/conversion to an unsigned type automatically includes an implicit `& TYPE_MAX` for the type.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you convert a uint8_t to a
>   uint16_t?

By simply assigning:

```
uint8_t  val_u8  = ...
uint16_t val_u16 = val_u8;
```

I think that the question you wanted to ask is "how do you *combine* uint_8 to a uint_16?"

<strike>I am guessing that you may have problem in the line</strike>

```
CO2Val = (buf[0]<<8)|buf[1];
```

if `buf[ 0 ]` is `uint8_t`. Cast it to `uint16_t` before doing the bit-shift to ensure room for the 8 bits (or else, the bits would "fall off" the MSB edge)

```
uint16_t CO2Val = ( (uint16_t) buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, at least for C. `buf[0]<<8` promotes `buf[0]` to `int` and performs the bitshift as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>My guess is that you're really using C++, not C, and the `buf[0]<<8` etc. are exhibiting undefined behavior due to the shift size being at least the width of the type.</strike> In C, this would not happen, since arithmetic operands are always promoted at least to `int`.

Anyway, let's try some simpler, more legible code:

```
packetBuffer.header[0] = co2Val/256;
packetBuffer.header[1] = co2Val;
packetBuffer.header[2] = humVal/256;
packetBuffer.header[3] = humVal;
packetBuffer.header[4] = tempVal/256;
packetBuffer.header[5] = tempVal;
```

and:

```
CO2Val = buf[0]*256+buf[1];
HumVal = buf[2]%16*256+buf[3];
TempVal = buf[4]%64*256+buf[5];
```

I've left in place your truncation of the upper bits of `HumVal` and `TempVal`, but it might be better practice to instead check for out-of-range values and issue an error of some sort.

**Edit:** Since OP clarified that the language is C, I'm unsure what is wrong. It seems we're still missing information. Perhaps looking at a dump of the buffers involved would be informative.

Comment: just so you know: your example code works like a charm in Vala for combining two uint8's into one uint16. Got two hexadecimal values as uint8 from a UDP package that should be treated as one uint16. Used your CO2Val example to get the job done and it works.